# max subarray brute force method yields large sum for first array

Tags: c++, arrays

I wrote a code for calculating the max subarray using brute force method.  My code reads a number of arrays from an input file and returns the output file, which contains the max subarray and the sum value.

Everything works fine except the first max subarray on the output file always contains a really large number at the end, which gets added to the sum value.  The subsequent sub-arrays don't have this problem.  I've included an example at the bottom of this post.

I can't figure out where I went wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the function that runs the algorithm and prints it to output file:

```
void a1(int a[], int size, string filename){ 

//run algorithm 1
int sum = a[0], start = 0, end = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    int tempSum = 0;
    int y = x;
    while(y>=0){
        tempSum += a[y];
        if(tempSum>sum){
            sum=tempSum;
            start=y;
            end=x;
        }
        y--;
    }
}

//print results on file
ofstream output;
output.open(filename.c_str(), ios::out | ios::app);
output << "\nMax sum array: ";
    for (int x = start; x <= end; x++) {
        output << a[x];
        if (x != end) output << ", ";
    }
output << "\nMax sum value: " <<  sum << "\n";
output.close();
}
```

Here is the main file:

```
int main() {
    int a[50];
    ifstream inputFile;
    string s;
    stringstream ss;
    string outputfile = "MSS_Results.txt";

//print title
ofstream output;
output.open(outputfile.c_str(), ios::out | ios::app);
output << "Algorithm 1:\n";
output.close();

//read file and run a1
int size;
char c;
inputFile.open("MSS_Problems.txt");
while (!inputFile.eof()) {
    getline(inputFile, s);
    size = 0;
    ss << s;
    ss >> c;
    while (ss.rdbuf()->in_avail()) {
        ss >> a[size];
        size++;
        ss >> c;
        if (!ss.rdbuf()->in_avail() && c != ']') {
            ss.clear(); 
            getline(inputFile, s);
            ss << s;
        }
    }
    ss.clear();
    if (size > 0) a1(a, size, outputfile);
}
inputFile.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Example of input file:

```
[1, 2, 4, -1, 4, -10, 4, -19, 18, -1, -3, -4, 11, 3, -20, 19, -33, 50, 66, -22, -4, -55, 91, 100, -102, 9, 10, 19, -10, 10, 11, 11, -10, -18, 50, 90]
[12, 12, 14, -88, -1, 45, 6, 8, -33, 2, 8, -9, -33, -8, -23, -77, -89, 1, 9, 10, 92, 87]
[565, 78, 33, 9, 10, 84, 71, -4, -22, -55, -10, 76, -9, -9, -11, 76, 89, 11, 10, -33, 9]
[2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Example of output file:

```
Algorithm 1:

Max sum array: 50, 66, -22, -4, -55, 91, 100, -102, 9, 10, 19, -10, 10, 11, 11, -10, -18, 50, 90, 3897136
Max sum value: 3897432

Max sum array: 1, 9, 10, 92, 87, 91
Max sum value: 290

Max sum array: 565, 78, 33, 9, 10, 84, 71, -4, -22, -55, -10, 76, -9, -9, -11, 76, 89, 11, 10, -33, 9, 87
Max sum value: 1055

Max sum array: 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 11
Max sum value: 103
```

As you can see, for the first array, there is a 3897136 that does not belong to the original array.

If I delete the first line from the input, the input looks like this:

```
[12, 12, 14, -88, -1, 45, 6, 8, -33, 2, 8, -9, -33, -8, -23, -77, -89, 1, 9, 10, 92, 87]
[565, 78, 33, 9, 10, 84, 71, -4, -22, -55, -10, 76, -9, -9, -11, 76, 89, 11, 10, -33, 9]
[2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Now my output looks something like this:

```
Algorithm 1:

Max sum array: 1, 9, 10, 92, 87, 624
Max sum value: 823

Max sum array: 565, 78, 33, 9, 10, 84, 71, -4, -22, -55, -10, 76, -9, -9, -11, 76, 89, 11, 10, -33, 9, 87
Max sum value: 1055

Max sum array: 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
Max sum value: 92
```

Comment: Your code is producing correct results on my computer.

Comment: Can I ask what you used to run this program?  I used PuTTY and it consistently produced that large number at the end.  Then I tried it on Visual Studio and it wouldn't give me any results at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initialized the array incorrectly, which is why it sometimes gave me a garbage number at the end.  To initialize properly, I simply changed

```
a[100];
```

to

```
a[100] = {0}
```

and that fixed the problem of abnormally large numbers at the end of the array.

I then moved `a[100] = {0}` into the while loop where the code reads the input file.  That seems to have fixed the new issue of reading wrong elements into the array.

Final unresolved issue: 0 at the end of array.

Will update once I solve that.

Comment: I don't think that solves your problem. If your program is accessing 'out of bounds' values then there's something wrong with you code or your input file. I mean your code will definitely produce intended result as including the garbage value(in your case, 0) won't maximise the subarray. Try printing your input, I think you'll get a 0 in the end.

Comment: You're right, there is still a 0 at the end, which doesn't affect the rest of my code, but definitely would like to get rid of it.  Any tips?

Answer (score -1):

Since all the problem is finding the maximum subarray , therefore the "large number" at the end *will* need to get added to produce the correct results.

In the first example that you provided, all the numbers were positive.
This means that the maximum sum subarray will actually be the sum of **all** the array elements.

Your algorithm part is OK;

Comment: It's at a really awkward spot that makes the output look like this large number is part of the first subarray.  Is there a way to remove it from my output?